# CUDA 10 and dkms on RHEL8

Tags: rhel, nvidia, dkms, cuda

I want to install CUDA according to the info on NVIDIA CUDA toolkit [site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=RHEL&target_version=8&target_type=rpmlocal)

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-rhel8-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel8-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf -y module install nvidia-driver:latest-dkms
sudo dnf -y install cuda
...
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides dkms needed by kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms-3:440.33.01-1.el8.x86_64
```

If I enable [epel](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) via

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable "codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-$(arch)-rpms"
[sudo] password for adminsafe20: 
Repository 'codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms' is enabled for this system.
```

it looks ok, but I don't see anything returning from `yum search dkms` except for:

```
============================== Name Matched: dkms ==============================
kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms.x86_64 : NVIDIA display driver kernel module
```

witch I get the same original message as before trying to install:

```
 - nothing provides dkms needed by kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms-3:440.33.01-1.el8.x86_64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't enable `epel`. You enabled the `codeready-builder` repo.

First, add the `epel` repo:

```
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

It's normally enabled by default after it's installed but if not:

```
dnf config-manager --enable epel
```

You can then install `dkms`.

Comment: I get "Error: No matching repo to modify: epel." after running these 2 commands